# How do I check what requests SOAPpy did?

Tags: python, soappy

I need to know what requests SOAPpy did. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

SOAPpy has a configuration object that you can use to set different properties. To see the requests you can use `dumpSOAPOut` or `dumpSOAPIn` or even a general `debug` option.

For a SOAP proxy you set it like this:

```
proxy = SOAPProxy(...)
proxy.config.dumpSOAPOut = 1
proxy.config.dumpSOAPIn = 1
proxy.config.debug = 1
```

.. for a WSDL proxy you can use it like:

```
client = WSDL.Proxy(...)
client.soapproxy.config.dumpSOAPOut = 1
client.soapproxy.config.dumpSOAPIn = 1
client.soapproxy.config.debug = 1
```

See here some extra options you can set on the config: http://soappy.ooz.ie/p/config.html